how to retrieve a youtube livestream chat messages?
i'm trying to make a simple youtube livestream chatbot but in reality all i need is to receive the messages on the chat in real time
i do not need any auth, don't need to post or delete any messages, just want to be able to see them on my code
now, the youtube official api has a very limited quota that makes it inviable to fetch the chat messages, as it would run out in an hour or two, which is not enough for any streaming
there are solutions that fetchs the chat without the need of the api using simple requests which also allows me to test on streams that are not mine which is VERY valuable, but not sure if using this would be against the terms of service, considering that if my tests are successful i do plan to offer this service to other streamers this is a big concern i have
the solutions i tried were the official api, but stopped when i saw the quota limits
and the solutions i mean are this one and similar ones for other languages: https://chat-downloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
this one already has everything i need but i want to know if i would be safe to use it without risking infringing the terms of service be for me or anyone using the result i make
